# Парсер возвращает только один ответ, вместо нескольких

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, beautiful-soup

Вот мой парсер, он ищет имена вакансий и возвращает только название первой вакансии, что может быть не так? Сразу скажу, что нахождение всей таблицы и переход на сайт использую селениумом, так как в дальнейшем буду пользоваться им

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxProfile
from selenium import webdriver
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
def perehod():
    user=UserAgent()
    profile=webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override',user.random)
    driver=webdriver.Firefox(profile)
    driver.get('https://rabota.ykt.ru/') 
    table=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('ul.r-vacancy_list').get_attribute('innerHTML')
    return table

#Это смена юзер агента и нахождение таблицы

def rabota(perehod):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(perehod,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    all_knopki=[]
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        all_knopki.append(knopka)
        return all_knopki

    #Это нахождение названий вакансий

def main():
    a=rabota(perehod())
    for i in a:
        print (i)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Вот ответ

```
Юрист
```

Мне надо, чтобы были названия всех вакансий, которые находятся на первой страницы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите `return` за пределы цикла `for`. На данный момент Ваша функция завершается после нахождения первой вакансии.

***Пример:***

```py
def rabota(perehod):
    soup=BeautifulSoup(perehod,'lxml')
    vacansii=soup.findAll(class_='r-vacancy_list_item ng-scope')
    all_knopki=[]
    for vacansia in vacansii:
        knopka=vacansia.find(class_='r-vacancy_title').text
        all_knopki.append(knopka)
    return all_knopki
```